# Image is not showing from external source

Tags: php, jquery

I have two pages: parse.php and media.php. At parse.php I have code:

```
<img src="http://localhost/dev4/admin/media.php/jjjffjjff"></img>
```

and now on media.php i have code like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var uri='<?php echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']; ?>';
var access_token = '<?php echo $_COOKIE['user_access_token'];?>';

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  'get_media',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            access_token: access_token,
            source_uri:uri
        },
        async: false,
        success:function(data){
            var text="<img src='http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/e/e0/Rotate-in-Volleyball-Step-4.jpg/670px-Rotate-in-Volleyball-Step-4.jpg'";
             $('body').html(text);
        },
        error:function(status){
            console.log('Error '+status);
        }
});

    });
</script>
```

**Image will be dynamic**

when i directly check **media.php/jjjffjjff** my image is coming. Why it is not coming on parse.php?

Comment: Replace `<img src="http://localhost/dev4/admin/media.php/jjjffjjff"></img>` to `<img src="http://localhost/dev4/admin/media.php/jjjffjjff" />` and `var text="<img src='data.media[0]['media']";` to `var text='<img src='+data.media[0]['media'];`

Comment: `var text="<img src='data.media[0]['media']";` this looks wrong. You probably need to escape the string for concatting the data values.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP ?

Comment: can you console log your "data" and show us it returns huh !

Comment: i am sending ajax request on media.php file to get corresponding image. and i am adding media.php file in img src of parse.php

Comment: `add console.log(data);` after `success:function(data){` actually nothing append ? check html source to be sure.

Comment: @HituBansal You are doing it all wrong, <img tags in parse page calling another page media in which image is displayed using <img tags ! why so complexity ?

Comment: I need this for some other reasons..

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
var text="<img src='data.media[0]['media']";
```

with

```
var text='<img src="' + data.media[0]['media'] + '">';
```

Comment: i did , i tried with 
var text="<img src='http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/e/e0/Rotate-in-Volleyball-Step-4.jpg/670px-Rotate-in-Volleyball-Step-4.jpg'";
             $('body').html(text);
        },

but parse.php is not showing image